# Mostrar datos en PyQt5 QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt5

Estoy haciendo mis primeras pruebas con `PyQt Model/View` y mientras que con `QTableView` he visto varios ejemplos de cómo mostrar los datos de unas listas en la tabla, con `QTreeView` no he encontrado un ejemplo sencillo.

Tengo los siguientes datos:

```
continentes = [‘América’, ‘Europa’]

países = [[‘Argentina’, ‘Colombia’, ‘Méjico’], [‘España’, ‘Francia’]]

ciudades [[[‘Buenos Aires’, ‘Córdoba’], [‘Bogotá’, ‘Cali’], [‘Ciudad de Méjico’, ‘Guadalajara’]], [[‘Madrid’], [‘París’]]]
```

Busco una salida de datos similar:

```
América
    |--Argentina
        |--Buenos Aires
        |--Córdoba
    |--Colombia
        |--Bogotá
        |--Cali
    |--Méjico
        |--Ciudad de Méjico
        |--Guadalajara
Europa
    |--España
        |--Madrid
    |--Francia
        |--París
```

Mi intento:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

continentes = [‘América’, ‘Europa’]
paises = [[‘Argentina’, ‘Colombia’, ‘Méjico’], [‘España’, ‘Francia’]]
ciudades [[[‘Buenos Aires’, ‘Córdoba’], [‘Bogotá’, ‘Cali’], [‘Ciudad de Méjico’, ‘Guadalajara’]], [[‘Madrid’], [‘París’]]


class TreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    def rowCount(self, parent):
        row_count = len(continentes) + len(paises) + len(ciudades)
        return row_count

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()
        return # ¿??????? AQUÍ ESTÁ MI PROBLEMA.

model = TreeModel()
view = QTreeView()
view.setModel(model)
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

Una segunda pregunta. ¿Sería más efectivo si los datos estuvieran agrupados de otra forma, por ejemplo en diccionarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondiendo a tus preguntas por orden.

### Con tu estructura de datos actual

No es necesario que implementes la clase `TreeModel()`, pues puedes usar la que ya viene en Qt llamada `QStandardItemModel`. Esta clase se crea inicialmente vacía (aunque tiene por defecto un elemento invisible que actuaría como raiz del árbol). A ese elemento vacío le vas añadiendo "filas" (los continentes en tu caso) usando su método `.appendRow()`. Cada una de estas filas ha de ser un elemento de tipo `QStandardItem()` (le pasas como parámetro el nombre del continente). A cada uno de estos elementos se les puede añadir sub-elementos, usando de nuevo `.appendRow()` sobre ese elemento (serían los países), etc.

Usando esta idea, podrías tener una función que rellene todas las filas, sub-filas y sub-sub-sub filas de la siguiente forma:

```
def rellenar_datos(model, continentes, paises, ciudades):
    raiz = model.invisibleRootItem()
    for i, continente in enumerate(continentes):
        hijo = QStandardItem(continente)
        raiz.appendRow(hijo)
        c_paises = paises[i]
        print("paises=", paises)
        for j, pais in enumerate(c_paises):
            sub_hijo = QStandardItem(pais)
            hijo.appendRow(sub_hijo)
            c_p_ciudades = ciudades[i][j]
            for ciudad in c_p_ciudades:
                sub_sub_hijo = QStandardItem(ciudad)
                sub_hijo.appendRow(sub_sub_hijo)
```

Tu programa principal sería así:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
view = QTreeView(headerHidden=True)
model = QStandardItemModel()
view.setModel(model)

rellenar_datos(model, continentes, paises, ciudades)
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

Pero como ves la función resulta bastante difícil de leer y no es muy genérica, pues sólo vale para el caso de que tengas tres "niveles" en el árbol, y cada nivel se pasa en un parámetro separado, y eso obliga a tener tres bucles anidados.

### Una estructura de datos mejor

Ya que el árbol que pretendes representar es una estructura de datos recursiva, estaría mejor almacenado en un diccionario que pueda tener dentro diccionarios, pues esto también es una estructura de datos recursiva que representa mucho mejor las relaciones entre padres e hijos:

```
datos = {
    "América": {
        "Argentina": ['Buenos Aires', 'Córdoba'],
        "Colombia":  ['Bogotá', 'Cali'],
        "Méjico":    ['Ciudad de Méjico', 'Guadalajara']
    },
    "Europa": {
        "España":    ['Madrid'],
        "Francia":   ['París']
    }
}
```

Como ves, el último nivel de este "árbol" contiene listas en vez de diccionarios. Esto será lo que nos permitirá rellenar el `QStandardItemModel()` mediante una función recursiva, que se llame a sí misma para añadir los hijos de un nivel dado, mientras los datos sean diccionarios, o que los agregue directamente si son listas:

```
def rellenar_recursivo(data, padre):
    if type(data) == list:
        for elemento in data:
            padre.appendRow(QStandardItem(elemento))
    else:
        for clave, valor in data.items():
            hijo = QStandardItem(clave)
            padre.appendRow(hijo)
            rellenar_recursivo(valor, hijo)
```

Como ves se le pasa a esta función los datos a añadir y el nodo que actuará como "padre", al que se deben añadir esos datos. Los datos recibidos en `data` pueden ser un diccionario si estamos en el nivel "top" de los continentes, o también si estamos en el siguiente nivel de los paises, pero serán ya una lista si estamos en el último nivel, el de las ciudades.

La función mira primero si `data` es una lista en cuyo caso simplemente la recorre para ir creando items que añadir al padre recibido como parámetro. Si no es una lista, asumimos que es un diccionario. Las claves del diccionario sirven para ir creando hijos, que actuarán como nuevos padres de los valores correspondientes. La función se llama recursivamente a sí misma para rellenar estos valores en los nuevos padres.

Desde el programa principal se usaría así:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
view = QTreeView(headerHidden=True)
model = QStandardItemModel()
view.setModel(model)

rellenar_recursivo(datos, model.invisibleRootItem())
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

El resultado se vería así:

[image: Captura]

Este método es más flexible pues se adapta automáticamente a cualquier número de niveles, e incluso a casos en los que la profundidad de cada rama del árbol pueda ser distinta (por ejemplo, podríamos añadir un continente "Asia", cuyo valor, en vez de otro diccionario, sea directamente una lista de países, y en este caso esa rama del árbol tendría sólo dos niveles de profundidad).